# How do I import a Shell32.dll function in C#?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm sorry for my naiveness, it's my first time dealing with DLLs.
I've been trying to run [ShellAboutA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellabouta) on a C# Application and had absolutely no idea how to. I googled and found a couple of questions and managed to come up with this code

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 ShellAboutA(
            IntPtr? hWnd,
            IntPtr? szApp,
            IntPtr? szOtherStuff,
            UInt64? hIcon);

ShellAboutA(null, null, null, null);
```

but once I ran it, it errored with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Generic types cannot be marshaled.'
```

(not only do I have no idea how to work with DLLs but I also have no idea what this means)

I'm guessing it's probably because they are all null. I checked the documentation again and everything but szApp is NULLable, so I tried this next function

```
            string _str = "test string";
            Int64 _int = Convert.ToInt64(_str, 16);
            IntPtr test = new IntPtr(_int);
            ShellAboutA(null, test, null, null);
```

and _int fails in `System.FormatException: 'Could not find any recognizable digits.'`
no matter how much googling I did after this, I found no solution.

Comment: Don’t make the parameters nullable

Comment: The problem is using `?` to declare your parameters as nullable. The marshaler doesn't understand nullable types, you need to use values like `IntPtr.Zero` instead. Note also that `szApp` may *not* be `null`, and should be marshaled as a `string` instead. Use `[DllImport("shell32.dll")] public static extern Int32 ShellAbout(IntPtr hWnd, string szApp, string szOtherStuff, UInt64 hIcon);` (the `A`, or rather `W`, will be taken care of automatically).

Comment: `IntPtr?` is just a shorthand expression of `Nullable<IntPtr>` which is why the error says it can't marshal generic types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you! That actually was the answer I needed. I removed the ? and made the szApp and szOtherStuff strings and now it works! btw how would I handle the icon? (also make your comment an answer so I can mark it as an answer)

Comment: Hadn't tested further, now I'm getting this once I close the about box `Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'notepad!scampad.Form1::ShellAboutA' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'`

Comment: Create or get a `System.Drawing.Icon` and pass its `Handle`. The last parameter should also be an `IntPtr`, in fact.

Comment: HICON should be IntPtr and why are you calling the ANSI version and not using Unicode

Comment: Not all dll's can be used in c#.  Old Win95 have to be wrapped in the c++ app.

Comment: @jdweng This is not win95 and this dll and this function can be called using pinvoke

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I agree that this function is not Win95.  The HWND cannot be null.  It must be a valid handle.

Comment: @jdweng The docs specifically state that `hWnd` can be `NULL`, but that maps to `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: What doc say hwnd can be null?  Only way hwnd can be null is if you are calling inside a form and trying to get the name of the form.  Most cases you are using a handle of a form to get details of the form.

Comment: @jdweng the link to the documentation of the function that is included in the question. It says "A window handle to a parent window. This parameter can be NULL."

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different issues with your existing code, so I'm just going to show you how it should look.

Note that `ShellAboutA` is the ASCII version of the function, `ShellAboutW` is the Unicode version. You can get C# to map it automatically, but it's best to specify it, and these day you should always use Unicode.

```cs
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int ShellAboutW(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    string szApp,
    string szOtherStuff,
    IntPtr hIcon);
```

You call it like this

```cs
ShellAboutW(IntPtr.Zero, "hello#whats up", null, IntPtr.Zero)
```

The first parameter is a `Handle` to a parent window, if necessary.

The last parameter is a `Handle` to an icon, if necessary. To use an icon, you can for example load it using GDI+.

```cs
using (var icon = new Icon(filePath))
{
    ShellAboutW(IntPtr.Zero, "hello#whats up", null, icon.Handle);
}
```

Comment: `BestFitMapping` has no effect here, since it deals with converting Unicode to ANSI, which is not happening here since you've explicitly asked for a Unicode function. Perhaps you were confusing it with `ExactSpelling = true`, which suppresses the `A`/`W` appending to the name and is more appropriate when the encoding is fixed. Specifying `LPTStr` for the strings is likewise unnecessary, since `CharSet.Unicode` already defaults to Unicode.

Comment: Thanks. I specifically left in `LPTStr` in case someone decided to switch to `ANSI` explicitly.

Comment: If they did, then the function would blow up, since `LPTStr` is always Unicode in .NET (confusingly, as `TSTR` is encoding-dependent on the unmanaged side), so there's really no point to deviating from the default marshaling here. If you did want to be explicit about it being Unicode for some reason you could use `LPWStr`, but that is only really a good idea if a nominally ANSI function is taking a Unicode parameter (for some reason -- I don't know if there are any such functions in Win32).

Comment: I agree that the attribute on the string is pointless since it just restartes the default